# Android - how to detect cheek press from a foreground Service?

Tags: android

i would like to get a callback when a cheekpress has occured. my defintion of a cheek press is:

**an event dispatched when human cheek presses against the phone.**

i thought about how this can be done by getting the android content view. so andorid.R.content and adding a touch listener to it but  then i saw on *PopUpWindow* they have this check :

[the method setIgnoreCheekPress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow#setIgnoreCheekPress())

is there something built into a viewgroup i can use to check for cheek press ?

i also saw in window manager there is this flag:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_IGNORE_CHEEK_PRESSES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected from my previous answer.  I actually looked at how PopupWindow works.  There is something built into Android for this.  PopupWindow is just setting the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_IGNORE_CHEEK_PRESSES;` flag on the window layout parameters for the window.  Doing the same will make cheek detection work as well as it does for popup window.  How well that works you'd need to see, I've never played with it.

Comment: isn't that what they're using to detect when the user picks up the phone and puts it near his cheek in the screen goes blank how did they know to make the screen blank when the user puts the phone near his cheek

Comment: @j2emanue I'm not absolutely certain, but I think they use the ambient light sensor to detect when a sufficient amount of light has been blocked by an object (such as your face) and there's a reason for the phone to be by your face (such as an active phone call).  But the solution in PopupWindow is just toggling that flag when you call setIgnoreCheekPress.